# Angular 2 application not working when moved into IIS virtual directory

Tags: angular, iis, angular2-routing

I have created a Virtual Directory on IIS (inetmgr) on my local PC and later converted it into IIS Web Application. The web application's root is: http://localhost/xyz/ When deployed and ran the application, I get the following error in the browser:

> All html components 404 not found errors.

Added rewrite rules in web.config. I changed index.html's base href to ./xyz or ./ but no luck.

If I deploy it to root directory, everything resolves - not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Enable `xyz` folder as a web application folder (See below picture)

[image]

#### 2. Update base href, for example `<base href="/spa/">`

#### 3. Set rewrite rule

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Hope it helps!