# Angular Routing IIS - rewrite only works on shallow paths

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, routes

Theres lots of questions on SO about this. I've read a lot of them, most of them point to sample web.config files that configure IIS rewrite. The closest post to my issue seems to be this:

[Angular 2 application not working when moved into IIS virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43017193/1286358)

However this has been down voted twice and seems to be dead, so instead of trying to resurrect it, I thought I would explain my issue here.

The code is hosted as an ASP.NET application at: http://127.0.0.1/angular-app/

the Angular code is built via the command: `ng build --base-href ./` and the the resulting `/dist/` folder is the code hosted at the local address above.

The IIS application has the following web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="./" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this set up these URLs will return the expected content:

http://127.0.0.1/angular-app/

http://127.0.0.1/angular-app/dashboard/

http://127.0.0.1/angular-app/heros/

The URL re-write rule is correctly pointing to the application base directory and so finds the `vendor.js, main.js`, etc files.

However with longer URI's the rewrite rule seems to only look one step back up the folder path for linked files. For example the URL

http://127.0.0.1/angular-app/heros/20/

Will correctly return the `index.html` and display "app-loading"

However digging a bit deeper it seems to be attempting to load the `vendor.js, main.js`, etc files from the base directory http://127.0.0.1/angular-app/heros/, only one step up rather than straight from the route.

These links are then also being redirected back to the `index.html` file and so none of the scripting is delivered to the browser.

I have tried using

```
<base href="/">
```

Instead of the `./` and amending the re-write rules accordingly, but this has the effect of always redirecting the content to http://127.0.0.1/

As suggested in the linked post, I changed the base href to:

```
<base href="/angular-app/">
```

and this returned the `index.html` from the correct location.
However the `vendor.js, main.js`, etc files were still being requested from the server root (http://127.0.0.1/)

I'm assuming i can fix this by simply hand editing the `index.html` file to point to the correct path from the root, but this seems like a hack rather than a fix.

Can anyone explain whats going on here, why does:

```
<base href="/">
```

Work for most people but not me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution,

Leverage the power of .aspx pages to stop using the relative paths. that way everything can be hard coded

I created a new default.aspx page in my /src/ folder, and copied the generated code from /dist/index.html

This code was then tweaked to this,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="src_Default" %>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>angular-app</title>
  <base href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/")%>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/favicon.ico")%>" >
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/inline.bundle.js")%>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/polyfills.bundle.js")%>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/styles.bundle.js")%>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/vendor.bundle.js")%>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/main.bundle.js")%>"></script></body>
</html>
```

Essentially resolving the bae of the asp.net app on the server and writing that out into all the references - including the `<base href="" />`

Then alter the `.angular-cli.json` file so it copies the Default.aspx and default.aspx.cs files across to the /dist/ folder on build

```
"assets": [
    "Default.aspx",
    "Default.aspx.cs",
    "web.config",
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

In the process I also discovered that this is the correct way to copy my web.config file over, I had been manually doing it - so thats a relief.

After a few IIS tweaks to ensure that default.aspx is higher in the default documents listing everything works.

Seems to be a solution for now but I can see this becoming an issue if those files ever get versioned.... but i'll cross that bridge when / if I get to it.